# Is it possible to cast a generic DataRow, which is based off of a typed DataRow, back to typed datarow using its attributes?

Tags: c#, datarow

I have an Oracle database full of similar tables (many common columns) which I use a dataSet to work with. Each table has a class to access the database including an extension method `updateInDatabase()`

I would like to create some methods which modify the common columns of the DataRows and return a generic DataRow. Is it possible to convert it back to a typed DataRow based on it's attibutes? I can see that the DataRow still holds information related to it's original type and table.

I'm guessing it would look something like this:

```
var typedDataRow = (genericDataRow.GetType())genericDataRow;
```

I am hoping to get the same result as the following but without knowing the type at runtime:

```
TypedDataRow typedDataRow = (TypedDataRow)genericDataRow;
```

When I try the above, the error is '; expected'

Comment: I don't see a problem with:`TypedDataRow typedDataRow = (TypedDataRow)genericDataRow;`  it might be the line above? You should give some more context.

Comment: I would like to update the row in the database no matter which type it is, so rather than write a switch statement for each table where I would use the TypedDataRow, I could just convert it and then update.

Comment: You sure that TypedDataRow is a data type and not an object?

Comment: @Dudemanword - It is an object created when you add a DataSet to your code through the Data Source Wizard. "Represents strongly named DataRow class"

Answer (score 1):

An extension method like this will be helpful

```
    public static T ConvertRow<T>(this DataRow row)
    {
        var obj = Convert.ChangeType(row, typeof(T));
        return (T)obj;                
    }
```

you can use it anywhere you want;

```
    TypedDataRow typedDataRow = genericDataRow<TypedDataRow>.ConvertRow()
```